# Bash redirect output to tty and file

Tags: bash, stdout

I'm trying to log some part of script execution. Logs should be displayed at second tty, and also written to a log file.

I can do it with a simple:

```
echo "Hello log" > /dev/tty2
echo "Hello log" > /var/log/my_logs
```

But it is very uncomfortable. I could also redirect echo to a particular place:

```
exec 1<>/var/log/my_logs
exec 2>&1
```

But how can I redirect STDOUT to both /dev/tty2 and /var/log/my_logs at once?

Comment: Wouldn't `tee` work? `echo "Hello log" > /dev/tty2 | tee /var/log/my_logs`

Comment: @fedorqui, in that case, you've already redirected stdout, so there's nothing for `tee` to see

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `tee`.

```
echo "Hello log" | tee /dev/tty2 /var/log/my_logs > /dev/null
```

(The final redirection is to prevent the output from appearing to standard output as well. You could also use `echo "Hello log" | tee /dev/tty2 > /var/log/my_logs`; there's no real difference between the two. `tee` just writes it standard input to both standard output and one or more named files.)

To redirect all of standard output to the pair, use a process substitution with `exec`.

```
exec > >(tee /dev/tty2 /var/log/my_logs)
```